# php exec a tail followed command and keep output

Tags: php

I want to output log file on the php page, including upcoming content.

Like this, but is not allowed by php.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
flush();
exec('docker logs server --follow', 'php://output'); // Follow log output
```

What's the best practice to continue executing output commands in a long time?

Comment: have you tried implicit flush. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

Comment: thanks buddy, I actually want to implement the `tail -f` command on the php page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a combination of `system` and streaming output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will work but I would try something like this:

```
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
// Clear, and turn off output buffering
while (ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_clean();
system('docker logs server --follow');
```

`system` directly sends output to the buffer, and `ob_implicit_flush` will do a flush whenever output is sent.  You may have to turn of gzip, and someother things.

I did do a `-tail` once for a server log, but it was years ago so I can't remember how I did it.  It was in an iFrame, so I could display it on a web page.  I remember that.

Comment: thanks guy, `popen` method resolved my problem. It exec the command in a stream.

Comment: Kool, glad I could help.